# jQuery File Paths

Tags: jquery, html, file

I'm trying to use jQuery to load a file into a textarea form for the project I'm working on, however, nothing actually loads when the button is clicked.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CodeEditor</title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#editor_area").load("test_file.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                    if (statusTxt == "success") 
                        alert("Load was performed");
                    if (statusTxt == "error")
                        alert("Load encoutnered an error");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Get Content</button>
    <main>
        <form>
            <textarea rows = "50" cols = "135" id = "editor_area"></textarea>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

Here's the relevant code. I'm thinking it's a problem with the file path because I tested jQuery and it was working fine.

EDIT: I added the statusTxt's and it alerts me with the error one.
EDIT 2: This code worked. I was hosting it on a local machine though. When I put the site on a web server, the code worked perfectly.

Comment: Are there in any errors in your console?

Comment: What is the client-side (javascript) error message?  What do the server access and error logs have to say about the request?

Comment: What does the Net tab of your developer tools show? Is the request made? Do you get the response you expect?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (although if I type into the textarea, it stops using the innerHTML for the default value, and the content stops loading if I click the button again then, but the successful alert still fires)

Comment: Reading `xhr.status` and `xhr.statusText` would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax request and **val()** instead of **load**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

         $.ajax({
           url : "test_file.txt",
           dataType: "text",
           success : function (data) 
                {$("#editor_area").val(data);}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```